# How to disable ArcGIS enterprise database feature edit version

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have created a new enterprise database in PostgreSQL. But when I want to edit feature class in ArcMap, I get the error:

> sde.DEFAULT no editable layer.

When I set editor options "Edit a version of the database with the ability to undo and redo" uncheck, the problem is solved. But every time I need to select this checkbox. Can I close it?

Comment: Please remember to provide ***complete*** information  about your environment with each and every post. The exact software version, table ownership, and logins used is required to begin to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to edit the default version of an SDE (Enterprise GDB) the DBMS account login must have the geodatabase admin role. you can read the documentation here
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/geodatabases/manage-postgresql/privileges-postgresql.htm

If you do not want to edit the default version then create a new version from the default, since you will be the owner you are able to edit fully. (Be sure your data source is in the correct version)

Comment: I have logged in with sde user that is full rights.

Comment: You seem to be confusing `protected` and `public` versions. The default `sde.DEFAULT` version property is `public`.